# SQL Server trigger update insert between table in different DB

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have three SQL Server databases on the same server. Before, I have to update/insert manually on all three databases using query. And now I want it to be done using triggers.

I have created a trigger, but on update, all rows on another table has been updated with identical data.

Below is the trigger to update other table on different database.

```
USE [QMS]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[afterUserUpdate]    Script Date: 07/14/2015 12:19:39 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[afterUserUpdate] ON [dbo].[USERTBL] AFTER Update
AS
BEGIN 
  IF @@rowcount = 0 RETURN;
    Update QMSFL.[dbo].UserTBL SET USERID=b.USERID, USER_NAME=b.USER_NAME, USER_LEVEL=b.USER_LEVEL,
    PASSWORD=b.PASSWORD, USER_GRP=b.USER_GRP, STATUS=b.STATUS, MODIFY_BY=b.MODIFY_BY,MODIFY_DATE=b.MODIFY_DATE,LOGON_IND=b.LOGON_IND,
    SUPERVISOR_ID=b.SUPERVISOR_ID,STARTDATE=b.STARTDATE,RESIGNDATE=b.RESIGNDATE,COMPANY=b.COMPANY,PABXID=b.PABXID,branch=b.branch
    FROM QMSFL.[dbo].UserTBL a
    INNER Join inserted b ON a.UserID=b.UserID
    WHERE a.userid IN (SELECT userid FROM inserted) 

    Update QMSUC.[dbo].UserTBL SET USERID=b.USERID, USER_NAME=b.USER_NAME, USER_LEVEL=b.USER_LEVEL,
    PASSWORD=b.PASSWORD, USER_GRP=b.USER_GRP, STATUS=b.STATUS, MODIFY_BY=b.MODIFY_BY,MODIFY_DATE=b.MODIFY_DATE,LOGON_IND=b.LOGON_IND,
    SUPERVISOR_ID=b.SUPERVISOR_ID,STARTDATE=b.STARTDATE,RESIGNDATE=b.RESIGNDATE,COMPANY=b.COMPANY,PABXID=b.PABXID,branch=b.branch
    FROM QMSFL.[dbo].UserTBL a
    INNER Join inserted b ON a.UserID=b.UserID
    WHERE a.userid IN (SELECT userid FROM inserted) 
END
```

and below is the after insert trigger. Not yet tested, caused I'm afraid something bad will happen like the update trigger. Seek your advise will this be ok.

```
USE [QMS]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[afterUserInsert]    Script Date: 07/14/2015 12:31:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[afterUserInsert] ON [dbo].[USERTBL] AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN 
  IF @@rowcount = 0 RETURN;
    Insert Into QMSFL.[dbo].UserTBL (USERID,USER_NAME,USER_LEVEL,PASSWORD,USER_GRP,STATUS,MODIFY_BY,
    MODIFY_DATE,LOGON_IND,SUPERVISOR_ID,STARTDATE,RESIGNDATE,COMPANY,PABXID,branch)
    Select USERID,USER_NAME,USER_LEVEL,
    PASSWORD,USER_GRP,STATUS,MODIFY_BY,MODIFY_DATE,LOGON_IND,SUPERVISOR_ID,STARTDATE,RESIGNDATE,
    COMPANY,PABXID,branch From inserted
    Insert Into QMSUC.[dbo].UserTBL (USERID,USER_NAME,USER_LEVEL,PASSWORD,USER_GRP,STATUS,MODIFY_BY,
    MODIFY_DATE,LOGON_IND,SUPERVISOR_ID,STARTDATE,RESIGNDATE,COMPANY,PABXID,branch)
    Select USERID,USER_NAME,USER_LEVEL,PASSWORD,USER_GRP,STATUS,MODIFY_BY,MODIFY_DATE,LOGON_IND,
    SUPERVISOR_ID,STARTDATE,RESIGNDATE,COMPANY,PABXID,branch From inserted
END;
```

and lastly, is it possible to have these after update/insert in one trigger.? and to provide an updated working trigger if possible.

Thanks...=)

***Update: in short, how to update multiple table in one trigger.***

Comment: Any reason you're not using built-in solutions such as replication? It's generally a bad idea to touch any resources outside of the same database within a trigger.

Comment: replication will replicate data in table usertbl in database QMS to table usertbl in database QMSFL/QMSUC. But in my case, table in database QMSFL/QMSUC is used by diferent application and can be updated independently. Table usertbl in database QMS will act as the master to update or add any data to all three database(like an admin).

Comment: for example: user using application with database QMSFL update their password. then this changes shall be removed during the replication. as that application only have access to that database only.

Comment: update works on the first table in QMSFL... but not on the second table(QMSUC) as all data on second table become dupicated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my final code done after a lot of searching and errors. Work as intended. May be of some help to others.

```
USE [QMS]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[afterInsertUpdate]    Script Date: 07/24/2015 12:00:33 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[afterInsertUpdate] ON [dbo].[USERTBL] AFTER Insert,Update
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
--BEGIN

    --add updated/inserted data into temp table
    Insert Into QMS.[dbo].UserTBLTemp (USERID,USER_NAME,USER_LEVEL,PASSWORD,USER_GRP,STATUS,MODIFY_BY,MODIFY_DATE,
    LOGON_IND,SUPERVISOR_ID,STARTDATE,RESIGNDATE,COMPANY,PABXID,branch)
    Select a.USERID,a.USER_NAME,a.USER_LEVEL,a.PASSWORD,a.USER_GRP,a.STATUS,a.MODIFY_BY,a.MODIFY_DATE,a.LOGON_IND,
    a.SUPERVISOR_ID,a.STARTDATE,a.RESIGNDATE,a.COMPANY,a.PABXID,a.branch
    From inserted a
    Left Outer Join QMS.[dbo].UserTBLTemp b
    ON a.UserID = b.UserID
    Where b.UserID IS NULL

    --remove unneeded character
    UPDATE UserTBLTemp SET USER_NAME=replace(USER_NAME,'''',' '),UserID=replace(replace(UserID,'''',''),' ','') WHERE UserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM UserTBLTemp) 

    --update data from temp table if exist in dest table
    Update QMSFL.[dbo].UserTBL SET USERID=d.USERID, USER_NAME=d.USER_NAME, USER_LEVEL=d.USER_LEVEL,
    PASSWORD=d.PASSWORD, USER_GRP=d.USER_GRP, STATUS=d.STATUS, MODIFY_BY=d.MODIFY_BY,MODIFY_DATE=d.MODIFY_DATE,
    LOGON_IND=d.LOGON_IND,SUPERVISOR_ID=d.SUPERVISOR_ID,STARTDATE=d.STARTDATE,RESIGNDATE=d.RESIGNDATE,
    COMPANY=d.COMPANY,PABXID=d.USERID,branch=d.branch
    FROM QMSFL.[dbo].UserTBL c
    INNER Join UserTBLTemp d
    ON c.UserID=d.UserID

    Update QMSUC.[dbo].UserTBL SET USERID=f.USERID, USER_NAME=f.USER_NAME, USER_LEVEL=f.USER_LEVEL,
    PASSWORD=f.PASSWORD, USER_GRP=f.USER_GRP, STATUS=f.STATUS, MODIFY_BY=f.MODIFY_BY,MODIFY_DATE=f.MODIFY_DATE,
    LOGON_IND=f.LOGON_IND,SUPERVISOR_ID=f.SUPERVISOR_ID,STARTDATE=f.STARTDATE,RESIGNDATE=f.RESIGNDATE,
    COMPANY=f.COMPANY,PABXID=f.USERID,branch=f.branch
    FROM QMSUC.[dbo].UserTBL e
    INNER Join UserTBLTemp f
    ON e.UserID=f.UserID

    --insert data from temp table if not exist in dest table
    Insert Into QMSFL.[dbo].UserTBL (USERID,USER_NAME,USER_LEVEL,PASSWORD,USER_GRP,STATUS,MODIFY_BY,MODIFY_DATE,
    LOGON_IND,SUPERVISOR_ID,STARTDATE,RESIGNDATE,COMPANY,PABXID,branch)
    Select g.USERID,g.USER_NAME,g.USER_LEVEL,g.PASSWORD,g.USER_GRP,g.STATUS,g.MODIFY_BY,g.MODIFY_DATE,g.LOGON_IND,
    g.SUPERVISOR_ID,g.STARTDATE,g.RESIGNDATE,g.COMPANY,g.USERID,g.branch
    From QMS.[dbo].UserTBLTemp g
    Left Outer Join QMSFL.[dbo].UserTBL h
    ON g.UserID = h.UserID
    Where h.Userid IS NULL

    Insert Into QMSUC.[dbo].UserTBL (USERID,USER_NAME,USER_LEVEL,PASSWORD,USER_GRP,STATUS,MODIFY_BY,MODIFY_DATE,
    LOGON_IND,SUPERVISOR_ID,STARTDATE,RESIGNDATE,COMPANY,PABXID,branch)
    Select i.USERID,i.USER_NAME,i.USER_LEVEL,i.PASSWORD,i.USER_GRP,i.STATUS,i.MODIFY_BY,i.MODIFY_DATE,i.LOGON_IND,
    i.SUPERVISOR_ID,i.STARTDATE,i.RESIGNDATE,i.COMPANY,i.USERID,i.branch
    From QMS.[dbo].UserTBLTemp i
    Left Outer Join QMSUC.[dbo].UserTBL j
    ON i.UserID = j.UserID
    Where j.Userid IS NULL

    --empty data in temp table
    Delete From QMS.[dbo].UserTBLTemp

--END
```